# Best compability file project export for .PSD file

Tags: adobe-photoshop, export, file-format

What is the best fully compatibility to export **(.PSD)** file project from Photoshop for software interchange purposes?

I mean, for example, I can edit the resulted export freely without loosing any feature from photoshop in Inkscape or Krita or other software.

Because I have tested in Inkscape, Krita and Paint.NET, and he text layer can't be edited automatically like in the Photoshop after directly importing.

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to throw out a shout for ORA (OpenRaster) format here for anyone who is looking. https://www.openraster.org/

This format likely does not support all photoshop specific features, but it aims to support the general representation of a layered raster graphics format with metadata in a very simple and reusable format for programmers to work with. All of the populat open source type editors (Krita, GNU Imp, etc) can work with it. From the programmer side it is a vast improvement over working with PSD format which is meant to store many Adobe specific features.

We can hope that more commercial raster editors start to take note of the standard in future iterations.

Answer (score 1):

**There is no such format!** PSD is as close as you can come, the next possible format down in line is PDF but you all ready lost quite much data on the way.

Comment: Thank you for your response, how can be there is no such format? I have just seen a detailed .psd file specifications in [**here**.](https://www.adobe.com/devnet-apps/photoshop/fileformatashtml/) It is written that _This document is provided for 3rd parties to read and write the Photoshop native file format_ and _"The Photoshop File Format describes the Photoshop PSD and PSB native file format in detail."_

Comment: @Unknown123 for there to be such a format would mean that all the other applications have all the features of Photoshop. For example paint and krita does not have the same kind of text engine so they couldn't do the text the same way. Likewise inkscape can not do all that photoshop does and photoshop can not do all that inkscape does. Also the PSD format spec does not entirely describe everything photoshop does it just describes how to extract the pixel datas of the format.

Comment: @Unknown123 For eample the specification just says that text engine data layers are  'Raw bytes for text engine' nothing more. So to implement it one would need to reverse engineer layer info.

Comment: Okay, so what is the highest compatibility format for exporting the file project file other than PDF? or maybe using 3rd party free plugin?

Comment: or what about .ORA? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenRaster edit: I can't find in the Internet how to convert .psd to .ora

Comment: @Unknown123 PSD is the best you can get. Its not like adobe has a interest to allow everybody jump ship